# Extracting a subgraph

Tags: python, optimization, performance, graph

Given a huge graph, I want to traverse it, in the fastest way possible, and extract a subgraph with the following properties:

- the starting node is specified
- the maximum number of elements and max depth can be specified
- if there are more links than the number specified, I want to save the information about the original number of links

To save all information I am using a class:

```
    class Link:
    def __init__(self, node, sons = None ,weight = None, depth = None):
        # name of the node
        self.node = node
        # number of links in the original graph
        self.weight = weight if weight is not None else 0
        # list of links in the reduced graph
        self.sons = sons if sons is not None else []
        # depth of the node with respect to the starting node
        self.depth = depth if depth is not None else 0
```

Note that the original graph is a dictionary, which can have loops.

```
    def reduce_graph(graph, start, max_depth, max_links = None):

        if start not in graph:
            return None

        to_visit = [Link(start, depth = 0)]
        visited = {}
        while to_visit:
            page = to_visit.pop(0)

            if page.depth >= max_depth:
                # we don't need to traverse this node, just save the number of links
                # in the original graph, if any
                try:
                    page.weight = len(graph[page.node])
                except KeyError:
                    page.weight = 0

                # let's make sure we will not visit this node again
                visited[page.node] = page
                continue

            else:
                # we are visiting a new node
                try:
                    # str(l) to ensure compatibility with imported json files
                    # saving at most max_links links
                    links = [Link(str(l), depth = page.depth + 1) for l in graph[page.node][:max_links]]
                    # number of links in the original graph
                    page.weight = len(graph[page.node])
                    page.sons = links
                    visited[page.node] = page
                    to_visit.extend([l for l in links if l.node not in visited])

                except KeyError:
                    # this node in not present in the original graph
                    page.weight = 0
                    visited[page.node] = page

        return visited
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You may be visiting nodes more than once, because you only check `if l.node not in visited` when adding nodes to `to_visit`. The node may be in `to_visit` already. The correct place for the check is right after `to_visit.pop(0)`.
- `to_visit` should perhaps be a `collections.deque` to benefit from the efficient `popleft()` function
- The comment says you use `str(l)` to ensure compatibility somehow. I'm not sure what you mean. I'm concerned because `str(l)` becomes `page.node` which is used to index `graph` again, which may not work depending on the original type of `l`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments; performance-wise, do you think it makes sense to keep `if l.node not in visited` even after adding the check after `to_visit.pop(0)`?
Regarding the last point: I have a JSON file of the form `'1' : [2,3,4,5]`. I am converting each element of the list so that I can use them as keys of the JSON itself

Comment: @meto Keeping the other check means checking twice for every new node, which sounds bad, but if you really want to know which is fastest you need to take some timings with real data.